# What is the difference between ohanashi and oshiete

Tags: grammar, words

In my Japanese book it gives the following examples:

> - Nihongo o hanashite mo iidesuka? Renshuu o shitai desu. = Do you mind if we speak Japanese, I would like to practice it.
> - ohanashi suru =  have a talk
> - Ohanashi dekite yokatta desu. = It was nice talking with you.
> - Motto oshiete kudasai! = tell me more
> - Anata no kazoku ni tsuite oshiete kudasai. = Tell me about your family

What's the difference between `ohanashi` and `oshiete`? They both seem to relate to talking/speaking, but I can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

おしえて (from おしえる) means "to teach".  So you can think of these examples as passing on information about the topic.

> - Tell me about your family　→　"Teach me information about your family" (even though we wouldn't say it that way in English)
> - "Tell me more (information about whatever we're talking about)"

Note that there is even a difference between はなす and はなし(を)する.  The former simply means "to talk" (the act of talking), while the latter means "to have a talk" (2 or more people actively engaged).

Comment: What's the difference in meaning between "the act of talking" and "having a talk". It seems quite similar to me? Thanks!

Comment: Let me ask you this:  "My boss is talking with one of my co-workers" vs "My boss is having a talk with one of my co-workers".  What kind of feeling does each one give you?